# How to access a specific field with json_normalize in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have this Json:

```
"customerDetails": {
    "city": "John doe city",
    "countryCode": "NL",
    "email": "john@doe.com",
    "firstName": "John",
    "houseNumber": "31",
    "salutationCode": "03",
    "streetName": "John doe street",
    "surname": "Doe",
    "zipCode": "9999"
},
"shipmentDate": "2019-11-04T20:27:30+01:00",
"shipmentId": 688016123,
"shipmentItems": [
    {
        "ean": "87193266436",
        "fulfilmentMethod": "FBB",
        "latestDeliveryDate": "2019-11-05T00:00:00+01:00",
        "offerCondition": "NEW",
        "offerPrice": 43.0,
        "orderDate": "2019-11-04T17:02:07+01:00",
        "orderId": "26354945747",
        "orderItemId": "BFC000032457457",
        "quantity": 1,
        "title": "Cheese grater"
    }
],
"shipmentReference": "081234500913463469",
```

When I want to get a dataframe from `customerDetails` i use this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([data])

d = json_normalize(df['customerDetails'])

print(d)
```

This works great, however when I try to use it on `shipmentItems` I get thrown an error. How to solve this to get the right columns in a dataframe from `shipmentItems`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible use `json_normalize` wihtout DataFrame constructor:

```
d = json_normalize(data['shipmentItems'])

print(d)
           ean fulfilmentMethod         latestDeliveryDate offerCondition  \
0  87193266436              FBB  2019-11-05T00:00:00+01:00            NEW   

   offerPrice                  orderDate      orderId      orderItemId  \
0        43.0  2019-11-04T17:02:07+01:00  26354945747  BFC000032457457   

   quantity          title  
0         1  Cheese grater
```